# KVM/Bridge: No Route To Host

Tags: ssh, virtualization, fedora, kvm

I've setup a VM on Fedora 17 with KVM and have configured a bridge network for the KVM. Both the host and the VM use manual IP configuration, with the host's IP as 192.168.0.2, the VM's 192.168.0.10.
From the VM I can connect to the host without any problems, but from the host I can't SSH to the VM,even though I still can ping the KVM from the host. Trying to ssh just gives me the result "no route to host".

Oh, I have iptables disabled so I don't think this is the problem of the firewall.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 2):

Also ensure that the kernel is configure for ip forwarding:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

It should have a value of 1, not 0.  If needed, enable with these commands:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways :

*** Using proxy tunnel to create a channel for host from guest :**
From guest run following command : 
**ssh -L 2000:localhost_ip:2000 username@hostip**

explore ssh man to get the inside.

*** Difficult to setup, but proper configuration while running guest :** 
follow 
http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~prathmesh/random.html#Connecting_qemu_guest_to_real_network